# What is the command line to print the output below (use built-in function of toupper from awk)?

Tags: linux, text-processing, awk

I have a text file which is a random file :

price.txt

```
orange  5   300 Florida
banana  7   500 California
apple   3   600 Maryland
grape   14  50  New Mexico
mango   30  1   Florida
tomato  45  100 California
melon   22  600 Texas
lemon   19  400 Florida
```

and I want to print this like below; (the $1 is all capital letters and the others are same as original file.)

```
ORANGE  5   300 Florida
BANANA  7   500 California
APPLE   3   600 Maryland
GRAPE   14  50  New Mexico
MANGO   30  1   Florida
TOMATO  45  100 California
MELON   22  600 Texas
LEMON   19  400 Florida
```

In this case , how do I command using awk "toupper" option?

Comment: see also [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 4):

Use:

```
awk -F'( )' '{ $1=toupper($1) }1' infile
```

the use of the field separator in regex mode and single space we defined with `-F'( )'` is to keep the indentation between the fields and keep the output beauty as input is, if you don't like beauty output, just remove it.

Answer (score 2):

With `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/\S+/\U$&/' < input.txt > output.txt
```

That would convert to uppercase the first sequence of non-spacing characters on each line.

If the input contains non-ASCII characters and is encoded in UTF-8, add the `-CS` option. If it's encoded as per your locale's charset, add `-Mopen=locale` instead.

If your input has columns with fixed widths (in terms of number of characters), you could use GNU `awk` and its `FIELDWIDTHS` way to specify columns:

```
gawk -v FIELDWIDTHS='8 4 4 *' -v OFS= '{$1 = toupper($1); print}'
```

Which in effect would convert to uppercase the first 8 characters of each line. Which you could also do with:

```
awk '{print toupper(substr($0, 1, 8)) substr($0, 9)}'
```

(`gawk` and POSIX compliant implementations of `awk` assume the input is text encoded as per the locale's encoding).

Answer (score 1):

Tried with GNU `sed` command and it worked fine

```
sed "s/^[a-zA-Z]*/\U&/1" p.txt
```

output

```
ORANGE  5   300 Florida
BANANA  7   500 California
APPLE   3   600 Maryland
GRAPE   14  50  New Mexico
MANGO   30  1   Florida
TOMATO  45  100 California
MELON   22  600 Texas
LEMON   19  400 Florida
```

Python

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
import re
k=open('filename','r')
for i in k:
    o=i.split(' ')
    b=o[0].islower()
    if (b is True ):
        up=o[0].upper()
        o[0]=up
        print " ".join(o).strip()
```

output

```
ORANGE  5   300 Florida
BANANA  7   500 California
APPLE   3   600 Maryland
GRAPE   14  50  New Mexico
MANGO   30  1   Florida
TOMATO  45  100 California
MELON   22  600 Texas
LEMON   19  400 Florida
```